# Можно ли сделать свойство по умолчанию у объекта?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть объект:

```
var obj = {
  name: "object",
  height: 12,
  default: false
}
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы, когда я ссылаюсь на объект была ссылка не на объект(obj), а на, допустим, свойство default(obj.default), но когда я ссылаюсь на свойства/методы объекта, то все работало нормально? 
Например так:

```
var t = obj; 
alert(t == obj.default) //true
var y = obj.name; 
alert(y == obj.name) //true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Можно

Но довольно костыльно.

```js
var initialObject = {
  name: "object",
  height: 12,
  default: false
}

// Создаем переменную obj, которая равна желаемому значению по умолчанию
var obj = initialObject.default;

// Прототипу объекта obj (в данном случае это Boolean) подменяем прототип на желаемый
Object.setPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), initialObject);

// Теперь, обращаясь к obj будет возвращено значение по умолчанию (потому что мы прямым текстом его установили в стр. 8)
console.log(obj);

// А при обращении к одному из свойств объекта initialObject (по сути, объекта obj), оно будет взято из цепочки прототипов (если будет найдено, конечно)
console.log(obj.height);

// Однако сразу же заметны подводные камни: поскольку мы заменили прототип глобального Boolean, то теперь любой объект, созданный соответствующим конструктором будет иметь в качестве прототипа initialObject
var drawback = (function(){return true}()).name;
console.log(drawback);
// или даже еще проще: console.log(new Boolean(true).height);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но да, слишком костыльно, и остальной код просто перестанет работать(наверное я просто буду использовать какую-нибудь функцию-фильтер.

Comment: @Frog самым правильным решением будет.

Answer (score 0):

Как на счет классов?

```
function Obj(name, height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
}

let defaultObj = new Obj(); //пустой Obj со свойствами name, height равными undefined
let customObj = new Obj("Ваня", "183"); //заполненный Obj
customObj.name; // "Ваня"
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне было нужно, я хотел не создавать новые объекты, а подменять ссылки на сами объекты, при наличии у них в свойствах default значений.